# Arrays with varying objects in them okay?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I needed an array that could hold different object types and thought I would need to use some form of inheritance but then realized it already works by default in Javascript:

```
var someArray = [];

someArray.push("Hello World");
someArray.push(12);
someArray.push(false);

alert(someArray.pop());
alert(someArray.pop());
alert(someArray.pop());
```

Seems to work in JSFiddle. This may be a stupid question but is there anything wrong with doing something like this? In my background with C, C++, C#, VB .NET, etc. arrays need to be of a single type so this sort of thing seems magic to me. Is this sort of thing okay to do or will it only lead to bugs and hair-pulling?

Comment: Actually you can so the same thing with C#'s `ArrayList` which isn't strongly typed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are not strongly typed in javascript, so there's no problem...

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is a dynamic language and it's array isn't strongly typed, so it's fine.
So does this:

```
var x = 12;     // Number
    x = "12";   // String
    x = {};     // Object
    x = [];     // Array.
    ...
```

Every variable can hold every type of object, It's not just with arrays...
When you use the `typeof` operator like:

```
if (typeof x === "string")
```

**You're not "querying" the x variable type, but the value it holds.**

- `C#, java, c++ ...`: Variable data types must be declared (static typing).
- `Javascript`: Variable data types are not declared (dynamic typing).

Comment: Another way to say it: Since you're never actually declaring a variable's type in JS anyway, how would the interpreter even know what should and should not be in an array? No type declaration; no type enforcement.

Comment: @Flambino. This isn't always right, google .NET `var`. Or read this: _"var. An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type. "_

Comment: @Flambino: I just figured it'd figure it out based on the first object inserted.

Comment: @RyanPeschel. If you're familiar with C#, you should know `var` here isn't like in `C#`...